How to catch `solve` failure in Picat?
I have a predicate that contains a solve call. It throws *** error(failed,main/0) when it has no solution. Is it possible to catch this error? Reading through the example file exs.pi I thought the following would do it, but it didn't.
import sat.
main =>
    catch(unsatisfiable,E,$handler(E)).
    
handler(_) => printf("Failed").

unsatisfiable =>
    {A,B} :: 1..2,
    A+B #= 1,
    solve({A,B}).

I'm using Picat version 3.6.

While writing this question, I did some more experiment and realized that solve is just a predicate like e.g. comparison operators, and therefore can be put into an if statement as follows:
import sat.
main =>
    if unsatisfiable then
        S = "Success"
    else
        S = "Failed"
    end,
    printf(S).

unsatisfiable =>
    {A,B} :: 1..2,
    A+B #= 1,
    solve({A,B}).

